# What is the Best SBC/mobile computing platform for ROS in 2020

Tags: control, ros, ros-melodic, state, 3d-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

Hope you are doing well.

I am currently trying to make a scale self-driving rally car. TBH I don't have much  idea about what I am doing but I made a some what functional self-driving car(In CARLA simulator), by doing courses from udacity, Coursera and udemy and I have no idea about computational complexity and stuff (I am not a CS/EE student). I have a 1/8 scale rc car as my computer carrying platform.

While doing testing ,I almost broke my laptop, on which ros was running and I am not willing to take that risk again.

I am using an Intel d435, an T265, A kinect v1, A Rplidar A1, A MPU 9250 IMU, A Neo 6m gps, 5 rotary encoders  and 3 arudino Megas.

(Must requirement) - I plan to use Gslam, Rtabmap, Particle filter, EKF and some other SLAM related custom packages which involves some image processing, path planning and control.

(Will try to do in future) - I intend to run a very complicated/detailed model for state estimation and control(MPC in real time maybe). I also plan to run a high frequency custom local planner(>100 Hz) and a global planner(~50 Hz).

What sort of computing platform might be suitable for me.

I was thinking about buying a 16 GB jetson Xavier but Since carrying  a  4-5 kg payload as a computing platform is not a problem for me, I was wondering should I buy a laptop around that price range. My budget is around 700 $(But higher performance to cost ratio is also a high priority after performance).

So, Is there any kind soul out there to give me some advice on what to do? Should GPU be a priority? I know my question is very vague, please feel free ask question to clarify.

TIA for taking the time to read my huge question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366016/what-is-the-best-sbc/mobile-computing-platform-for-ros-in-2020/) by [SamFlynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/57290/samflynn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am considering using a Intel NUC, quad core myself.  The Intel RealSense team tests on NUC, so an especially good option if you are planning to use D435.  You only need a 19V supply, and it should top out at 30 W.  You will need an SPI adapter, but something like a Total Phase (or cheaper options from eBay) should let you plug all your devices on the USB.

---

Originally posted by [henry10210](https://answers.ros.org/users/67117/henry10210/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me i tested Jetson Nano and it can challenge with my laptop GTX950M GPU. But for finding reasources side it's not that good. Cause most example in the web doing RC Cars with Rpi so if you want to go easy way , for troubleshoot or talking with developer i can suggest Rasppi. Also Nvidia doing great job day by day with answering questions and developing community but like i said most people using Raspberry(Price/Performance).

---

Originally posted by [Morgenstern](https://answers.ros.org/users/55396/morgenstern/) with karma: 25 on 2021-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1